# $P(X>0|X+Y)$ where X,Y have poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

X,Y both have poisson distributtion with parameters $\lambda$ $\nu$ accordingly:
I have to calculate
$$P(X>0|X+Y)$$, my first question is, does this mean I have to calculate it for every $j$ where $X+Y=j$ , because I am not sure if I understand this correctly.

If I am, $$\frac{P(X+Y=j\space\cap X>0)}{P(X+Y=j)}=1-\frac{P(X+Y=j\space\cap X=0)}{P(X+Y=j)}=1-\frac{\nu^{j}}{(\nu+\lambda)^{j}}e^{\lambda}$$ , but something must be wrong with this calculations, since when j=0, the probability should equal to zero, but it is not.

Comment: Are they independent?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to add it

Comment: Then $X + Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda + \nu)$.

Comment: I am aware, used it in my calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost $\mathbb P(X=0)$ in last equality:
$$
1-\frac{\mathbb P(X+Y=j, X=0)}{\mathbb P(X+Y=j)}=1-\frac{\mathbb P(Y=j)\cdot\mathbb P(X=0)}{\mathbb P(X+Y=j)} = 
1-\frac{\nu^{j}}{(\nu+\lambda)^{j}}.
$$
This probability is equal to zero when $j=0$.

Comment: Ouch right thanks!